# QGIS and ArcGIS common edit for Postgresql

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, arcgis-10.5

I have created a database with postgis(v2.2.1) template in postgresql 9.5 version. Once created database, I used  [Create Enterprise Geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-enterprise-geodatabase.htm) geoprocessing tool existing database via Arcgis (10.5).

And now I can create new feature in database with ArcCatalog. But I can not use this feature table in QGIS.

If I create a geometry table with plain sql like this:

```
create table mypoints (id serial, name varchar, geom geometry(Point, 4326));
```

this time arcigs will not use `mypoints` table.

I could not create a common solution. How can I do this? Or is tihs possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. I've done nothing but open database work with ArcGIS and PostgreSQL for the past four years. You have not specified any versions of any software, nor the table ownership and schema information, which is likely where your problem exists.

Comment: Updates postgresl and arcgis versions

Comment: Okay, now include several paragraphs of details about the exact procedures you used to create and access the tables. The exact PostGIS version is necessary as well

Comment: @vince where are the several paragraphs of details you mentioned earlier?

Comment: I've been waiting for them too.